# Swift - Unable to open file in target Xcode 10

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode10

I am trying to run Aplication which I have downloaded from GitHub.

When I run get error unable to open file in target, I have Xcode 10.

I already searched for solution and get this one.

I had the same problem, but in Xcode 6.1.1 - what fixed it for me was to change the configuration file setting to **None** for the two Pods-related targets, then run pod install again.

The configuration file setting is found by selecting the project (not the target) and then the Info tab.

But cant find configuration file location.

Here is the error picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ql3M5.png

Answer (score 56):

A solution I found to work for me was

Inside the project root directory

```
root
  |- <ProjectName>
  |- <ProjectName>.xcodeproj
  |- <ProjectName>.xcworkspace
  |- <ProjectName>Tests
  |- Podfile
  |- Podfile.lock
  |- Pods
```

Delete the following files.  Ensure you have copied the contents of Podfile.

1. Podfile
2. Podfile.lock
3. Pods Folder

Open your .xcodeproj using Xcode or using terminal command

```
open <ProjectName>.xcodeproj
```

Inside Xcode, locate the "Pods" folder which should contain something along the lines of...

```
Pods
|- Pods-<ProjectName>.debug.xconfig
|- Pods-<ProjectName>.release.xconfig
```

Delete those references and select "move to trash" when prompted.

Close Xcode

Now run the following:

```
pod init && pod install
```

Open your Podfile and paste in your previously copied old Podfile that was deleted earlier.

run the following command:

```
pod install
```

In terminal open Xcode again with the following command

```
open <ProjectName>.xcworkspace
```

**Note**: that I opened the `xcworkspace` file NOT the xcodeproj file.

At this point for me I was able to compile my code as normal without having to change back to the Legacy Build System.

Comment: Awesome solution! This worked for me. Much better than using the legacy system. This should be the top answer.

Comment: This is how answer should be provided step by step.Excellent answer.

Comment: Why there are a references in .xcodeproj that should be deleted although it's the first time to clone the project and "pod install"

Comment: @AhmedSaeed I believe what you are asking is when you clone the project you do not see the xcodeproj? It really depends on how the maintainer has chosen to establish the project.  It is possible to commit and upload all the pods for a project.  This is not the recommended approach however it affords cloners the ability to compile without the need to run `pod install` or have cocoa pods at all. By default, when you instantiate pods based project, it will create a workspace for you and this should be committed in the repo.

Comment: For reference: Cocoapod documentation https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html @AhmedSaeed

Answer (score 45):

In File -> Project setting -> select **Legacy Build System**

Make sure you have opened .xcworkspace file and pod installed properly.

Comment: when i run pod deintegrate and pod install get error No such module 'SwiftSocket'

Comment: 1) pod repo remove master
2) pod setup
3) pod install . try this

Comment: Why you are suggesting people to use Legacy Build System? Makes no sense. The solution that @user1171911 provided works perfectly.

Answer (score 21):

Reinstall the pods to get everything cleaned up:

```
pod deintegrate
pod cache clean --all
pod install
```

Comment: that worked for me, using XCode 13 where the legacy system is not an option anymore

Answer (score 12):

**This happened due to change the Project Name or Miss the Pods from Your Project**

**if the Pods are Miss Then Following Method**

1. open the Project and Command + Shift + K
2. Close the Project
3. Open Terminal got to Your Xcode Project Directory **cd /your-Xcode-project**
4. if coca pods are already installed so skip this Point if not **sudo gem install cocoapods** run this Command on terminal
5. pod install

**If Above Method not Working so its Project name Issue then Go with following Method**

1. First, open your Pod File and change the target
2. target 'your Xcode project name' do

run the Following Commands from Terminal

go to Your directory from terminal

> pod deintegrate

> pod clean

> pod install

**Done now open your xcWorkSpace file**

Answer (score 10):

For me it works, update the version of CocoaPods and reinstall the pods

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Comment: Yes, we need to update the `cocoapods` I was using 1.5.3 version where it wasn't able to `deintegrate` the project properly. Had to use the updated version to do that. I am using XCode 11.1 now.

Answer (score 8):

Run following commands after you have downloaded Xcode project from GitHub:

```
cd /your-xcode-project
pod install
```

This worked on Xcode 10.2.

Answer (score 7):

I had this issue too with project I cloned from GitLab. Your error looks extremely similar to mine. I solved it by running this in Terminal:

```
cd path/to/your/project
pod install
```

When I checked project folder in Finder, there was a Podfile. But same project viewed in Xcode had nothing under 'Pods' module. From this I figured out the pods are not installed (or installed properly?) and installing them solved this error.

If there is *some* Pods or .xcworkspace file, it might be worth doing `pod deintegrate` before installation - just to be sure :)

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same error opening an old project in a new macbook with a recent installation of Xcode and no cocoa pods or anything related on it.

My way to fix this was following some of the steps en the [issues #1727](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/1727) of alamofire and change some things. Open the terminal and cd project where the pod file is.

So, this is what worked for me:

- sudo gem install cocoa pods
- pod repo remove master
- pod setup
- pod repo update
- pod install

Then just, clean build folder and build the project.

Comment: This also works after you renamed whole project name

Answer (score 4):

1. Quit `Xcode`
2. Open `Terminal`
3. Change to directory (where podfile is present)
4. `pod install`

I was trying to do `pod install` after removing unwanted pod(steps 2,3 & 4), but it still was not working. Quitting Xcode (steps 1, 2, 3 & 5) worked.

Answer (score 2):

If you suddenly start seeing this issue on an existing project, before you try anything else, try

- pod update
- Make sure your pod build settings looks good
- Clean build folder
- Retry building

Answer (score 2):

1-
in xcode 
menu --> project --> clean build files

2-
close project

3-
in terminal
cd

4-
in terminal
pod update

5-
re-open 
project..xcworkspace file

6-
clean, build

good luck

Answer (score 2):

delete file name "Podfile.lock" and try pod install again.

Comment: Isn't this the same as just running 'pod update'? In which case it will update to newer versions of the specified pods.

Answer (score 2):

Just stumbled into the issue recently myself. It seems it's a [bug](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8091) in CocoaPods.

Possible fix:  `gem install cocoapods --pre`

Answer (score 2):

I tried below and error went away !!

project name - SwiftExample

Went to Pods -> Info -> Configurations -> Debug
Change to None for Pods-SwiftExample

Code compiles even after setting it back to original.

Comment: This solution worked for me. I came here from this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55558984/3151873

Answer (score 2):

I can see many solutions already given there. But I believe the easiest way to resolve this problem is

1. Open the project directory in Terminal
2. Delete .xcworkspace file
3. Run pod install

That's it. The newly created .xcworkspace file will work without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

Open your project file (project.pbxproj) and check of 'Pods' is added to the path before the 'Target Support Files' folder.  Remove that and i got it to build fine.