# IOS Compilation Error Genexus 16 u8 SmartDevices Generation

Tags: ios, xcode, genexus, genexus-gam

Good morning,
I am working on compiling my iOS app con Genexus 15 U8.

Execution Type: Simulator (Mac)

The process starts and then it gives me the following error:

error:

> error: / Users / frames / Library / CloudStorage / iCloud Drive /
>   Library / CloudStorage / iCloud Drive / Documents / Projects /
>   EventDay / NetSQLServer / EventDay / Pods / Target Support Files /
>   Pods-EventDay / Pods-EventDay.debug.xcconfig : unable to open file (in
>   target "EventDay" in project "EventDay") (in target 'EventDay' from
>   project 'EventDay') Failed: iOS Compilation Failed: Run EventDay

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Marcos, do you still have this problem?
Does the file exist into the remote directory?

I would suggest to rename the mobile folder from your model and rebuild all.
If you open this project on xcode and run it from there, do you have the same error?

Here there is another thread that can help:
It recommends goint to File -> Workspace setting -> select Legacy Build System
//make sure you have open .xcworkspace file and pod installed properly

[Swift - Unable to open file in target Xcode 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53117077/swift-unable-to-open-file-in-target-xcode-10)